# Play MP3 in browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to allow a user on my site to click a button and via an ajax call load an mp3 file that is created on the server to their browser and then begin playing that file. The file cannot be publicly accessible sense it contains user account specific information. So, I've created the server side code that creates the mp3 but I do not know how to stream the file to the browser from my controller. Here is my current controller method.

```
def play_mp3
    t = TextToSpeech.new(current_user, "Play this text in the saved mp3 file")
    mp3_file = t.text_to_speech
end
```

Comment: In your controller code you can return arbitrary data with [`send_file`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html).

Comment: @tadman Ok, so I am able to use this to save the file from the browser, but how would I load this in with javascript so the user could essentially hit play and the file is created on the server and then played in their browser?

Comment: Your browser doesn't care how it got the file, only that it did. Presumably you can use some JavaScript widget that plays music from remote sources, of which there are dozens. If you have a URL that returns valid MP3 data, it's going to be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<audio autoplay controls="controls">  
   <source src="/YOURMP3FILE.mp3" />  
</audio>
```

Comment: Didn't realize it would be that simple but this essentially is what I'm after. Thanks

Comment: That'll work in some browsers some of the time, but there are JavaScript wrappers around the `<audio>` that make it work on more browsers more reliably. This minimal solution is a great start though.